# How to select a label text in browser pop in selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Can someone please help me how to select "Logitech UE 4500" in web browser popup.

PSB for HTML got through "driver.page_source".

```
<list id="bluetooth-paired-devices-list" role="list" tabindex="0">
<div class="spacer" style="height: 0px;">
</div>
<div role="listitem" class="deletable-item bluetooth-device"     paired="paired">
<div>
<div class="bluetooth-device-label">Logitech UE 4500</div>
</div>
<button class="raw-button row-delete-button custom-appearance"     tabindex="-1" title="Delete this item">
</button>
</div>
<div class="spacer" style="height: 0px;">
</div>
</list>
<div role="listitem" class="deletable-item bluetooth-device">
<div><div class="bluetooth-device-label">KKHAMPOX-MOBL2</div>
```

Comment: Hi Anzel,Tried below but didnt work

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'Logitech UE 4500')]").click()

Comment: driver.find_element_by_cssselector(".bluetooth-device-label > .Logitech UE 4500").click()

Comment: **'Logitech UE 4500'** is an **innerHTML/text** and not a **"class"**, hence what you've tried won't accomplish what you want.

Comment: @MuraliPerumal, if this is a pop up, you need to ensure you **click** it when it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to **click on the element with text 'Logitech UE 4500'**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bluetooth-device-label' and contains(text(),'Logitech UE 4500')]").click()
```

**Note:** The above xpath will locate the **div element with class 'bluetooth-device-label' and contains innerHTML/text as 'Logitech UE 4500'.**

Comment: No luck, got the error : FAIL: Unhandled NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2258.2)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13 (d94adb104175dc6837398cb4c45e99aeb2a38ba2),platform=Linux 3.10.18 x86_64)'

Comment: Hi All, It worked with : driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"bluetooth-device-label") '
            'and text()="' + 'Logitech UE 4500' + '"]').click()